# Publish an orthophoto without needing mxd file

Tags: arcgis-server, mxd

I wonder if anyone has a tool or a method that can help me to Publish an orthophoto without the need to include it in mxd file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Catalog pane in ArcMap, or from ArcCatalog itself, you can right-click on your raster and select Share as Image Service.

[image]

This will open the Share as Service dialog (similar to the dialog you'd see if you publish from an MXD using File > Share As > Service)

[image]

From here you can enter the parameters you require and publish your image service.

[image]

You can publish an image service from a Raster dataset if you have ArcGIS Server, however you will need both  ArcGIS GIS Server and ArcGIS Image Server (or ArcGIS Image extension in 10.3/10.4) if you want to publish Mosaic datasets.  More info can be found at **[Publishing image services](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/publishing-image-services.htm)**

Comment: Thanks Midavalo and vince. your answers are very helpful,but what is the advantages of using image service? or what makes it better or preferred to use more than map services?

Comment: @FatinRIMAWI I am not an expert in either, so you may wish to do research on this elsewhere, however I believe that publishing a map service doesn't make the raster directly useable in other services, whereas I think if you publish an image service you can use it in other services, similar to using a layer in a map.  That said I could be completely wrong on that as I've never actually used an Image service